# Are there environment variables for "c:\program files" and "c:\program files(x86)"?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Any standard environment variables for those two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the output of `set` in cmd.exe:

```
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
```

So yes, there is %ProgramFiles% and %ProgramFiles(x86)%

Comment: And [here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows) a list of environment variables on Windows

Answer (score 2):

If you run the

> SET

command from a command prompt window it gives you the following information:

```
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
```

so these are:

```
%ProgramFiles%
%ProgramFiles(x86)%
```

respectively...